# Save token that comes in response to Api

Tags: angular, laravel, ionic2

I'm trying to save the token that my server sends on every request. Although apparently "Authorization" is present in the response, I can not print the value.

**The code is:**
[image: ionic2]

**The server returns:**
[image]

**What I can print to the console:**
[image]

**On the server I'm using a middleware for cors:**
[image]

How can I get the token that is coming from Header Authorization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks that you did not expose the header correctly, the browser will not forward this header to your code unless you specify it.

try adding this to you `$headers` object

```
'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' => 'Authorization'
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!